# Laravel 4 search function validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got an problem.

How could I validate an search function? Like if it fails to find the user, it'll display an error message. I've tried several things, but none of them works. Here's my form:

(search/search.blade.php)

```
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@search') }}" method="get">
<div class="input-append span9">
    <input type="text" class="search-query" name="character" placeholder="Character/guild name">
    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

I've tried to do something like: `@if ($searchResult->count())` - it works, but it displays every time I enter the search site.

Here's my controller's acction:

```
public function search()
{
    $name = Input::get('character');
    $searchResult = Player::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
    return View::make('search.search')
            ->with('name', $name)
            ->with('searchResult', $searchResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
@if(count($searchResult) > 0)
  //Show results?
@endif
```

Comment: Pretty feasible to me. No need for complicated solution

Comment: Laravel's eloquent implements a count() method for counting results and what is displayed above would work but his problem is that he is using one action to display a search form and display the results.

Comment: Even if he kept it on a single action, it should still work. using `count($searchResult)` you would probably reduce the step of performing `isset($searchResult)` as the `count($searchResult)` takes care of it.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues

Comment: If its going to work with count($searchResults) why wouldn't it work with $searchResults->count()? Why run a database query every time the page is loaded?

Comment: @DanielOR, I don't see an issue with your code, but why waste on 2 steps, when you can finish it in one. Secondly, you can still ignore the additional query if `Input::get('character')` is empty. Keeping it on a single action has its own advantage, you don't have to have a seperate action for managing `pagination` or `paginating  for the search made already`

Comment: Both solutions can work, but the point is to separate logic. I probably wouldn't use the one view for display results and for displaying the search form. You could fit crud into one method but splitting it up is a better practice and in the end will make the program easier to maintain/update/debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your controllers methods into getSearch() to display the search form and then use postSearch() to display the results.

```
public function getSearch()
{
    return View::make('search.search');
}

public function postSearch()
{
    $name = Input::get('character');
    $searchResult = Player::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
       return View::make('search.search')
            ->with('name', $name)
            ->with('searchResult', $searchResult);
}

//search.blade example

@if(isset($searchResult))
    @if($searchResult->count() > 0)
        //display results
    @else
        //no results to display
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Here's my view: http://paste.laravel.com/J6o , also here are my routes: `Route::get('characters/search', 'CharactersController@getSearch');
Route::post('characters/search', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'CharactersController@postSearch'));` The problem is the browser doesn't change the form action, it's still `<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="<?php echo URL::action('CharactersController@search'); ?>" method="get">` I thought it's browsers cache, I've changed three browsers.

Comment: change action="<?php echo URL::action('CharactersController@search'); ?>"  to action=""

Comment: also you will have to add a foreach in there. 
@foreach($searchResults as $s)

Comment: Changed, but still it displays the same error. Whenever I change something in the action, it doesn't change. I've tried different browsers, but nothing. Could you write the form in laravel's form system?

Comment: Can you paste your controller?

Comment: Your Form action still is pointing to `URL::action('CharactersController@search');` which should now point to `URL::action('CharactersController@postSearch')`

Comment: @erm_durr, why not use the Form Blade Helper? `{{Form::open(array('url' => 'characters/search', 'method' => 'post'))}}` instead of creating the whole form tags, you might reduce on some issues. Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form

Comment: @Abishek R Srikaanth yeah, I usually use that, but I have a special search box and things like that, never customized it..

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth Solved everything, just it always displays the error message, I've used `if(isset($searchResult))` Here's the view: http://paste.laravel.com/Jvn